# Python print statements not appearing in Teamcity console

Tags: python, teamcity, stdout, locust

I have a simple `locust` script running in a custom step in Teamcity.

There is a connection error that only happens from Teamcity and not from my local run in PyCharm, so I added `print` statements.

They do not appear in the Teamcity console.

Maybe related:

```
  [2021-10-03 15:45:57,824] BuildAgent4/INFO/root: Terminal was not a tty. Keyboard input disabled
```

So I tried adding
`PYTHONUNBUFFERED=TRUE` before the call to `locust`, but no help.

I read something about using `sys.stdout.flush()`, but where would I call this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple!

Just put
`sys.stdout.flush()`
right after the `print` statement!

Make sure to `import sys`.

That's all, folks.

Comment: Or you can use the flush argument for print: print("Hello, World!", flush=True)

Comment: Oh, and the stuff about "terminal was not a tty" is unrelated, it only relates to sending keystrokes *to* locust (to ramp/up down manually)

Comment: Also, PYTHONUNBUFFER=TRUE *should* work. Maybe you forgot to export it?

Comment: I meant PYTHONUNBUFFER*ED*..